Nextjs portfolio app stuck page load estimation time
I’m working on my portfolio website but it’s not fun anymore. The development process has been a hassle due to the compilation time. When I run the command npm run dev it takes really long for the page to load in localhost, sometimes over 10 minutes. This made me to abandoned using nextjs for a while but I had to finish up my portfolio regardless. Now the darn thang doesn’t compile anymore. It’s stuck at “ready in 7.0s” this is nerve wrecking on so many levels.
I’m using vscode on a windows machine, node-20.3, next 14, and tailwindcss 3.3. Any solution would be highly appreciated. Thanks!
There’s not much solutions available online regarding my problem. I restarted uninstalled and reinstalled node, did the same with vscode with no luck
